# Peewee - bulk delete based on list of records

Tags: python, peewee

How to create similar operation in Peewee? This is SQLAlchemy code:

```
for record in records:
    session.delete(record)
session.commit()
```

This code delete all the records within one SQL delete statement.

I tried using following code. But it creates single delete statement for every record:

```
with db.atomic():
    for record in records:
        record.delete_instance()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting multiple records in a table using join in Peewee?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33290336/deleting-multiple-records-in-a-table-using-join-in-peewee)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a list of IDs, say:

```
list_of_ids = [r.id for r in records]
query = MyModel.delete().where(MyModel.id.in_(list_of_ids))
query.execute()
```

You can also, with some databases, use a subquery instead:

```
records = MyModel.select().where(...)
query = MyModel.delete().where(MyModel.id.in_(records))
query.execute()
```